# Redirect all webpages to www with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been trying to redirect my subdomain pages to force them to be at www. 
The thing is, if I try **example.example.com** it will perfectly redirect to www.example.example.com, in the other hand, if I try **example.example.com/whatever.html** it won't redirect. My .htaccess file looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#subdomain non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$` from the `RewriteCond` line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10896415)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it was supposed to provide an answer.  It was apparently the wrong answer, but it was an answer and not a comment.